# Удалить ответ бота Discord

Tags: java, discord

Можно как-то удалить поступивший ответ от бота на команду ?
(Человек пишет команду , бот отвечает и через какое-то время ответ бота удаляется)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182243/deleting-user-messages-in-discord-py

Comment: так это удалить сообщение с командой (пользователя), а мне надо  удалить ОТВЕТ БОТА на команду !!!

Comment: `await message.delete()` ?

Comment: нет эквивалента async / await в Java

Comment: А джава, а я чет проглядел, думал питон. Ну это тогда: `channel.deleteMessages(msgs).queue();` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535789/discord-bot-wont-delete-messageseclipse-ide-java-with-jda-api)) ?

Comment: оказалось все намного проще : 
`Channel.sendMessage(toSend).queue( message -> message.delete().queueAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) );`